# how to update key of $_SESSION array with php variable value

Tags: php, arrays, session, key

I have an issue I cannot seem to find the answer of anywhere. So I am placing it here.

I have following variables stored in $_SESSION variables :

```
$_SESSION["pr_first_name"]  ="Thomas";
$_SESSION["pr_middle_name"] ="Richard";
$_SESSION["pr_last_name"]   ="Peterson";
```

Now I need to access, change and then save the `$_SESSION array` keys and their values. I have written the following code for this:

```
extract($_SESSION);
```

this gives me the variables with the name of `$_SESSION` keys, now I need these variables to be saved as further keys of `$_SESSION` arrays. How can I save the php variables as keys to `$_SESSION` array?

Comment: `$_SESSION[$var] = $value`?

Comment: you want to echo the value saved in session variable is that what you want?

Comment: You mean replace the existing keys with new values?

Comment: No not replace, rather to save new keys and values with name reference to previous keys

Comment: Try this (if really needed and you have done `extract($_SESSION);` before): `foreach($GLOBALS as $k => $v){if(array_key_exists($k,$_SESSION))$_SESSION[$k]=$v; }`

Comment: After your last comment, i thing you should show an full example of what you want to do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to use the `extract()` method for whatever reason, then you can use this approach, but you **shouldn't use `extract()`** for such a **global scope** as $_SESSION is:

```
$_SESSION["pr_first_name"]  ="Thomas";
$_SESSION["pr_middle_name"] ="Richard";
$_SESSION["pr_last_name"]   ="Peterson";

$keys = array_keys($_SESSION);
extract($_SESSION);
...
...
foreach($keys as $key){
    $_SESSION[$key] = ${$key};
}
```

But much better and simpler way is to use the $_SESSION as normal array:

```
$tmp = $_SESSION["pr_first_name"];
...
$_SESSION["pr_first_name"] = $tmp
```

Comment: Using `extract()` in globals scope is a nasty messy thing to do and should be avoided at all cost

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Definitelly agree, but we don't know OPs intention - maybe it's just for testing. Updated the answer.

Comment: Better, but it is more related to not using `extract` in a piece of code that is in the global scope. Better to only use it when within the scope of a function, then it does not affect the programs global variables and all the new variables are destroyed once the function is finished

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is an array, but to comparmentalise data you can create arrays within that array.

If you do that with your data, you would not need to rename the keys in the the name value pairs as they will be unique within the new sub array.

WARNING: Using extract in the global scope is nasty, it sprays variables into your global scope that later will only confuse you or the person that has to maintain your scripts.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["pr_first_name"]  ="Thomas";
$_SESSION["pr_middle_name"] ="Richard";
$_SESSION["pr_last_name"]   ="Peterson";

$t = array(
            'pr_first_name'  => $_SESSION["pr_first_name"],
            'pr_middle_name' => $_SESSION["pr_middle_name"],
            'pr_last_name'   => $_SESSION["pr_last_name"]
        );

$_SESSION['new_names'] = $t;


// now amend the new occurance in SESSION however you like
$_SESSION['new_names']['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$_SESSION['new_names']['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$_SESSION['new_names']['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
```

Alternatively, if you have a bigger list of occurances in $_SESSION that you want to copy.

```
session_start();

function new_names($sess)
{
    $picks = ['pr_first_name', 'pr_middle_name', 'pr_last_name' ];
    $new = [];
    foreach ( $picks as $name) {
        $new[$name] = $sess[$name];
    }
   return $new;            
}

$_SESSION["pr_first_name"]  ="Thomas";
$_SESSION["pr_middle_name"] ="Richard";
$_SESSION["pr_last_name"]   ="Peterson";

$_SESSION['new_names'] = new_names($_SESSION);

// now amend the new occurance in SESSION however you like
$new = $_SESSION['new_names'];
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
```

And of course if you had used this compartmentalisation from the beginning. it would be even easier to create a new set of data

```
$_SESSION['first']["pr_first_name"]  ="Thomas";
$_SESSION['first']["pr_middle_name"] ="Richard";
$_SESSION['first']["pr_last_name"]   ="Peterson";

$_SESSION['new'] = $_SESSION['first'];
$new = $_SESSION['new'];
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
$new['pr_first_name'] = 'Some new value';
```